# Gender of Street Names and Village Locations

Tags: new-latin, place-names

I can find references on the gender of countries and cities, but nothing on street names or small locations (say within a village). Transcribing Manorial Records of the late 17th century, I have a village green called "The Ring" and other locality / agricultural areas with names Puxey and Shepney. Do rules exist for this level of location or are there references others have found? The main challenge is when adjectives are used e.g. adjungen etc.

For reference, these are the Manorial Records, specifically Court Baron records which are legal documents and pre-1733 are in Latin. They include local place names in English. As an example (needing case endings sorted):- "scituat<um> et existen<s> in Oppido de Stalbridge prope quendam locum ib<ide>m vulgo vocat<um> <th>e Rings". Chevrons show the reversal of contractions and suspensions. To properly transcribe we need to understand the gender given to local locations.

Answer (score 5):

If I were using a non-Latinized place name like this in my own writing, I would avoid situations where it stood alone: instead, I would use it in apposition with a descriptive Latin noun, and attach agreeing modifiers (such as adjectives) to the appositive noun rather than the name itself.

From what I can see, your example looks like it takes a similar strategy to what I envisioned using: the proper name is placed inside a prepositional phrase in "in Oppido de Stalbridge", and inside a participle clause in "locum ibm vulgo vocat e Rings".

I am not sure if there is a way to accurately assume the gender of the name itself.